# What is the origin of "Why don't you..." as a suggestion or command?

Tags: word-usage, questions

Frequently, in spoken dialogue one hears the above phrase used as a suggestion to the listener (or sometimes more strongly, as a command):

- *Why don't you give me that book?*
- *Why don't you go to the store and get some more milk?*
- *Why don't you make me a sandwich?*

In these examples, the speaker is clearly not asking for the reason the listener is *not* doing the action in question. It's true that the listener is not actually doing the action (yet), but there is no particular reason for the inaction. The listener is simply unaware of the speaker's desires.

In the instances above, *"Why don't you ..."* could be replaced with *"Would you ..."* and the meaning would be the same. The latter sounds more natural to me.

What is the origin of the *"Why don't you ..."* phrase and when did it come into use? Is this a regional usage?

Comment: Actually, "Why don't you..." in most cases could be reduced even further to "Please...".

Comment: If someone says *why don't you* to me, I explain why I don't.

Comment: [Why don't you](http://www.bbc.co.uk/cult/classic/titles/whydontyou.shtml) for Brits of a certain age...

Comment: If you particularly want to reduce it further, simply state the command.  "Give me that book."

Comment: I think it's less of being a direct command and more provoking the thought of the listener, and when they can't find a good reason to refuse, they'll promptly do what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

The expression suggests a command especially when used by itself with a question mark at the end. When  used as in the sentences you show it suggest more a kind of polite request (much more common ) . Both usages dates back to the beginning of the 19th century and their usage has been increasing since then especially as a polite request form.

[Why don't you](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/why+don't+you%3F)?

> - a  question tag that is put onto the end of a command.
>
>   - Andy: Move aside, why don't you? Bob: Okay. Sorry. I didn't know I was in the way. "Just keep bugging me, why don't you?" threatened Wally. Andy: Try it again, why don't you? Sue: I hope I get it right this time.

Source: McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Why%20don%27t%20you&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhy%20do%20not%20you%3B%2Cc0)Why don't you

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Why%20don%27t%20you%3F%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhy%20do%20not%20you%20%3F%3B%2Cc0) Why don't you?

Comment: The ngrams don't really work. They only seem to surface *why do not you* literally. That is not the common phrase.